# nfs share error

Tags: fedora, nfs

I have a error in configuring nfs share.
not able to view the nfs directory after showmount command.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: yes , in /etc/exports i did the necessary config. it has been exported with the destination ip address

Comment: i am trying to configure it in vmware workstation. i have created a two vm server with fedora. One server side and the other one is client side. from server side i am trying to export the share to client side.

Comment: yes 134 is the client server. i am using fedora 29 as a vm server

Comment: Hi and welcome! Thanks for contributing! But please, don't post images of text ([read this for reasons why](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text)).

Comment: still have the error

Comment: Did you run `exportfs -a` after editing `/etc/exports` ?

Comment: You always need to run `firewall-cmd --reload` after adding either a port or service.